# Trying to pick div randomly, but it echo empty div sometimes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to pick div randomly. The only issue in my code is that it will randomly pick one empty div sometimes. I don't understand why it will echo one empty div sometimes. I have use chrome inspect element to check, there is no empty div. What did I do wrong on the foreach loop.

```js
var divs = $(".widget").get().sort(function(){ 
            return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //so we get the right +/- combo
           }).slice(0,1);
$(divs).show();
```

```css
.widget{
display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php


foreach ($widgets as $widget){
   echo'<div class="widget" >';
   echo $content; 
   echo'</div>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: How does `foreach ($widget as $widget)` work?  That code doesn't break?

Comment: There's no `$content` on your loop (or anywhere else).

Comment: I am not very familiar with JQuery but I would say you return an empty div because the DOM has not completed parsing yet. You should be doing iy on load event or JQuerys ready.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for any weird `sort` function to get a random element out of the jQuery collection. Here's one way to do it with `eq`.

```js
var $widgets = $('.widget');
var length = $widgets.length;
var div = $widgets.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * length));
div.show();
```

```css
.widget {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">1</div>
<div class="widget">2</div>
<div class="widget">3</div>
<div class="widget">4</div>
<div class="widget">5</div>
<div class="widget">6</div>
<div class="widget">7</div>
```